# Find Replace By Regular Expression in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I want to remove all statements like .setText("") in eclipse IDE by find/replace (CTRL+F).

But i didn't know the regular expression for that. Could you help me.

Comment: Define `like .setText("")` - what are some examples of `like .setText("")`?

Comment: i want to remove all empty setText() statements.

Comment: examples are : txtFld1.setText(""); , txtFld2.setText(""); etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
\.setText\(""\)
```

You will have to escape the `.` and the brackets, because they have special meanings in regex.

To remove also the part before the `.` use

```
\S*\.setText\(""\)
```

`\S` means not a whitespace

`*` zero or more

Comment: this finds all the .setText("") statements. But how to find all occurrence of someTxtFld.setText(""); ?  i tried with * but it did not work.

Comment: @gt_ebuddy see my update. The `*` is a quantifier in regex, it makes the character before match 0 or more times.